# How to resolve cannot /get/product error after submitting value in heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMwp1.png)I am working on a full stack project using MERN. In local everything was working properly but after deploying it to heroku I am getting this error as attached below. All other apis are working properly in heroku. But after clicking on save button for creating product with admin credentials i am getting this error. Can anyone please help me regarding this. This happens to only one specific url. Data will get stored in db . For product update its working properly. Can anyone please help me on this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8yNt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use this api as

`/api/admin/product` instead of `/admin/product`. Seems like proxy works only for url's starting with `/api`

Comment: all urls start with /api/... for same url while prodcut updation it works properly. Even reloads it to same page as expectd